# Python on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I think I have some problems with the python installation on OS X 10.8. Here's what I get after `which`command

```
$ which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Then I have

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.5
```

While

```
/usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.5.6
```

I have homebrew installed. The problem is that a program (Tex Live Utility) crashes because it needs Python 2.6+ and uses `/usr/bin/python` as path. My question is, which is the python version that comes with OS X? How do I fix this problem without messing up Apple's Python installation?

By the way, in the /usr/bin folder I have the following

```
$ ls py*
pydoc           python2.5       pythonw
pydoc2.5        python2.5-config    pythonw2.5
pydoc2.6        python2.6       pythonw2.6
pydoc2.7        python2.6-config    pythonw2.7
python          python2.7
python-config       python2.7-config
```

Comment: And you can always start a program using "python2.6 app.py"

Comment: @user2799617 OSX 10.8 as written in the question. And I can always start a program with python2.6 for sure, but I can't always modify a program that contains python scripts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `/usr/bin/python` is the Python that comes with OS X.
- `/usr/local/bin/python` is the Homebrew version.

This also explains why the 2nd one is newer. Also, if you have Homebrew installed, everything under `/usr/local` has been installed by Homebrew (normally).

**P.S.** I'm a little bit suspicious as to why your OS X Python is at version 2.6.5; in OS X 10.8, the Python that comes bundled should be 2.7.2 as is the case on my system:

```
$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.2
```

Comment: That's what I was wondering. As you can see, in `/usr/bin` I have  also python 2.6 and 2.7, but the executable `python` points to python 2.5. I found how to change os x default python version here http://superuser.com/questions/35256/how-can-i-change-the-default-python-version-on-snow-leopard, but I'm not sure if it is ok or if it will mess up the system

Comment: I think it shouldn't mess anything up, and if it does, you can change it back; besides, 2.7.2 already should be the default version, not 2.6 or 2.5.

Comment: Ok, now I changed the default version and the program works as expected. Thank you for your help!